# SELECT usuario por Data

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um `Select` mysql que busca meus clientes pegando o nome, email pela data do dia...

Preciso pegar os resultados que são do dia de hoje `(WHERE data_cad='$dataHoje')` e preciso selecionar um a um para enviar um email para ele (vou usar `mail ()`)

A minha dúvida principal é como selecionar UM a UM e fazer o Envio Um a Um.. Me faltou a lógica para isso...

Grato!!

Comment: Você pode selecionar todos, e dar um while enviando os e-mails ou se o conteúdo dos e-mails for o mesmo pra todos você pode fazer um array com os e-mails e mandar para todos em um envio só, não é mais fácil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá, como você não especificou a quantidade média de e-mails vou criar um exemplo simples de como fazer isso:

*Vou usar PDO para as consultas, mas podes fazer a seu gosto*

```
$select = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM minhaTabela WHERE DATE(timestamp_field) = CURDATE()");
$select->execute();

$rows = $select->rowCount();

if($rows >= 1){
   while($ftc = $select->fetch()){
      $para = $ftc["email"];
      $assunto = "Assunto do email";
      $msg = "Sua mensagem aqui";
      $headers = "From: seuEmail@seudominio.com" . "\r\n" .
                 "CC: copiaOculta@dominio.com";

      $enviar = mail($para, $assunto, $msg, $headers);
      if($enviar){
         echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso";
         sleep(5);
      }else{
         echo "Erro";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Olá Leo Letto, por e-mail eu não tenho como buscar só por data, pois vou selecionar pela data o email do cliente que se cadastrou nessa data.. tem como dar um exemplo para o envio para cada um?

Comment: Nesse caso use só o select com base na data de execução do script, é essa sua dúvida, selecionar pelo dia?

Comment: Eu quero pegar o e-mail do cliente via where $data_hoje, e enviar um a um...

Comment: Tem experiência com PHP Mailer? Para envios em grande quantidade ele é mais recomendado, podes acabar sujando o nome do seu domínio mandando muitos e-mails as configurações certas

Comment: Leo Letto, Eu utilizo a função mail(), já sei como enviar, vou enviar dentro do While, mas falta pegar um a um para fazer o envio, vai ser poucos envios..

Eu tenho isso... mas não ta funcionando... $consulta= $conn->prepare("SELECT EMAIL FROM usuarios ORDER WHERE data_cad='$data_hj'); $consulta->execute(); while($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $email = $linha['EMAIL']; }

Comment: Dentro do while, ele já vai percorrer cada um dos registros retornados pela pesquisa do mysql, basta você mandar o e-mail dentro do while que ele vai ir pra todos um por um

Comment: Exatamente isso, só não ta funcionando como eu fiz...Pode me dar um exemplo? E Como faço para dar um ECHO e ver cada E-mail impresso na tela, para mim testar..

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo vê se é o que precisa

Comment: Consegui aqui...Valeuu

Comment: Coloquei um sleep() de 5 segundos para dar um descanso entre os envios, fique a vontade para tirar se quiser.

Comment: Valeu @Leo Letto